# fcm push notification unathorized

Tags: android, postman, fcm

С помощью postman отсылаю post запрос на https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Body raw

```
{
    "to":"dnk7jIusElk:APA91bEMDST3DoZ8EqOSDSIcJ2hGr16gT5JAGGR2q_j2wEqdHyFazpzP6_Mvlf_KlDV9jcdadS_kqF_GgvMIdNCsj5hKQaO_Q6K_i57wAw9axqHO8rOV1GVoIZsemSZJhXZD2Fn4WHC8",
    "data":{
        "message":"{
            "order_id":"23475625",  
            "order_number":"9857", 
            "order_type":"autoselect",   
            "order_area":"МСК - Войковская",
            "client_name":"Всилий",
            "client_tel":"+79998885533",
            "order_task":"В комнате не работает радиатор.",
            "order_date":"2019-12-28",
            "order_time":"09:00"
        }",
        "title":"This is a title.",
        "body":"This is a body text",
        "tickerText":"Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here",
        "vibrate":"1",
        "sound":"1"
    }
}
```

В header выставляю два ключа

```
Content-Type application/json
Authorization key=****
```

В ответ приходит

```
Unauthorized
Error 401
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Разве что ключ не тот... Покажите скрин какой ключ и откуда взяли

Comment: Да так и есть. Навигация консоли firebase запутанная в одном месте api key - поставил его сначала, а потом нашел в настройках server key

Answer (score 1):

Не в том месте посмотрел server key. Поставил нужный и все заработало + экранировал кавычки в json